# Paypal - send amount from server

Tags: angular, paypal

This is the first time I'm trying to implement payment in my site and there are few things with paypal I find little hard to grasp.

In my app user can upload as many videos as he want to translate.
each video can be translated to more than one language.
The total price is calcualted from the videos duration and the requested languages that the user selected.

In the simplest way possible, I added this code to my site

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
      <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myFakeBusinees">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_name" [value]="transactionId">
      <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
      <input type="hidden" name="amount" [value]="totalPrice">
      <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" (click)="submit()">
      <input type="submit" value="Paypal"/>
    </form>
```

In paypal I configured a returnUrl to my server and after the payment , I display user with a summary.

My problem with this approach is that the user can change the amount hidden field from the client. Altough I can check the payed amount in my server after the call to returnUrl, I don't want to enable this situation.

I tried to read the server api, but I'm not sure it does what I want.
I thought about the following flow, and wonder if the is correct and if paypal supports this.

The flow:

- User create an order in client . Each order has a transactionId
- When user click pay button, the client sends a request with the transactionId to server.
- Server calculates the the totalPrice, and send payapel to create a token for this amount. server returns token to client.
- Client recive the token and is being navigated to paypal.
- In paypal site, user choose his payment method and pay. Paypal server than returns the a confirmation for this token to myserver.
- My server check the token against the transactionId, and if everything is ok display user with a "Your order was created" page.

Any help will be really appreciated. It was a little hard for me to figure out the flow from the documentaion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you want to do is to call `createOrder` API in backend ( see nodejs code below ) when user clicks on the pay button and get the `return_url` and `cancel_url`
from front-end using window.location eg: window.location.origin + '/success-url' so that there is no problem while testing on local server, 
stage and production. Then when the user is redirected to `https://example.com/success-url`, `paymentId` and `PayerID` will be passed by 
payapal in the URL itself, then from that page you can call `executeOrder` in your backend.

Here is the link to [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/create-process-order/)

Below is a sample nodejs code:

```
exports.createOrder = (data, callback) => {
  /* First step when user clicks 'Pay with paypal' on place-order screen */
  var create_payment_json = {
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
      "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
      "return_url": data.return_url,
      "cancel_url": data.cancel_url
    },
    "transactions": [{
      "amount": {
        "total": getAmountFromNoOFVideos(),
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "description": "Video Translation"
    }]
  };

  paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
    if (error) {
      callback(error);
    } else {
      if(payment.payer.payment_method === 'paypal') {
        for(var i=0; i < payment.links.length; i++) {
          var link = payment.links[i];
          if (link.method === 'REDIRECT') {
            redirectUrl = link.href;
          }
        }
      }
      callback(null, redirectUrl, payment.id)
    }
  });
}

exports.executeOrder = (data, callback) => {
  /* Second and final step in place-order screen */
  let paymentId = data.paymentId;
  let PayerID = data.PayerID;

  var details = { "payer_id": PayerID };
  paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, details, function (error, payment) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("\x1b[31m", "PAYPAL ERROR: ", error)
      callback(error);
    } else {
      callback(null, true);
    }
  });
}
```

The Paypal flow:
- Assume your website link is `www.videotranslate.com`

1. User clicks **Pay** button on your website `www.videotranslate.com`
2. You make an AJAX call to API `www.videotranslate.com/api/createOrder` 
   from your Angular Component / Service ( depending on your design )
3. In the success function of the AJAX call you get the `redirectUrl` 
   from the `createOrder` function in backend.
4. When user has made payment through paypal successfully paypal will 
   redirect the user to `www.videotranslate.com/success-callback`
5. Now on this page you make an AJAX call to API 
   `www.videotranslate.com/api/executeOrder` from Angular
6. In case user cancelled payment on paypal, paypal will redirect user to 
   `www.videotranslate.com/cancel-callback`, here you can show an error 
   toast and ask user to pay again.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your help.
Can you please help me with few questions:
1.who is calling createOrder ? my client or paypal
2.what is the flow of the request - who (client,server,paypal) is calling each function?
3. if the execute order does the payment transaction , why do I need to use the createOrder for ?

Comment: 1. Your client calls `createOrder`. 2 I edit ans to demonstrate the flow